# Sumproduct and countif questions

Tags: excel, countif, excel-indirect, sumproduct

I have a workbook that has a separate sheet that is assigned to each classroom teacher.  In the column A of each sheet I have the student's names from their rosters listed, in column B I have it set up for them to place an "x" for each incomplete assignment for these particular students.  Under my Roster sheet I want the workbook to search through each of the 30+ teacher sheets and find the names of each student and calculate the number of "x's" by their name throughout the sheets and report that info in my "Roster" sheet.   Essentially counting how many incomplete assignments each student has throughout.  This is the formula that I have on my Roster sheet: =SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("'"&Sheetss&"'!A:A"),A2,INDIRECT("'"&Sheetss&"'!B:B"),"x"))

"Sheetss" is the range that I have defined for all of my teacher sheets.

My issue with this is that inside my first teacher sheet I can type a student's name (StudentB) in column A and an x in column B, it will return a 1 for StudentB on my Roster sheet, however, when typing StudentB on any other sheet and an x in column B on any other sheet it will not count that data and show a 2, 3, etc.

I feel as though the formula is not searching all of my sheets for data any help would be great.  Thanks!!

Comment: I cannot reproduce what I think you described. Can you insert any screenshots? I created some dummy data and copied what I have on the sheets to the same sheet so you could see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPINH.png

Comment: You would be probably better off having one single sheet where you have 3 columns: Student's names, Teacher's name, Incomplete assignment and then one separate sheet that would pull out the data you want for one specific teacher and/or student. You are essentially using Excel as a simple database here. Having 30 sheets is likely to cause all sorts of issues later on starting with performance.